# Why do Stack Exchange sites give you 101 reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Why do Stack Exchange sites give you 101 reputation when you register, when there is only 100 given for an Association Bonus?

> [image]

Comment: Because you start with 1 without the bonus.

Comment: See this post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work

Answer (score 3):

The minimum amount of reputation a user can have is 1. A *bonus* of 100 gives you a total of 1 + 100 = 101 reputation points.